# AWS Step Functions State Machine Result Selctor from SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-step-functions

I am building my first simple AWS Step Function:
Step 1: Read a message from SQS
Step 2: Run a Redshift query

I have managed to setup my initial workflow & permissions to the resources. I am trying to format my

Here is my Result Selector code for the first step:

```
"ResultSelector": {
        "startTime.$": "$.Body.startTime",
        "endTime.$": "$.Body.endTime"
      }
```

Here is the error output:

```
{
  "error": "States.Runtime",
  "cause": "An error occurred while executing the state 'ReceiveMessage from SQS' (entered at the event id #2). The JSONPath '$.Body.startTime' specified for the field 'startTime.$' could not be found in the input '{\"Messages\":[{\"Body\":\"{\\\"startTime\\\": 12828373, \\\"endTime\\\": 12828374}\",\"Md5OfBody\":\"1ca004b811be50a7579f3a7e6affaeb1\",\"MessageId\":\"5b6b72d6-3fb7-451a-9053-26b72de32768\",\"ReceiptHandle\":\"AQEBjgttgZBNSuGZb0LFjo16Xc2+5uc48k9QPh9af4vTGy1xzb/BZZ6mBFx0FQ4ALWUoLfppWHIJbb7Zax2+Jv2dqekvLoCWWrdjasyrJnGfduXwsY20cPuW86kXz4RJfP4qbnyvWcV5Cb63u26XUE3S+3AqREo2BNwi01mI3ceYWxguXzgSgDIMg/07Lt5kBcNvB6qCIexQDMDgH91ZmmINLuX0j5gd3spHCmzBvFoQKv4PbLBS18PsC6vL1YLGxplZ+eVyzD3eoK/5AU0jqmI0l0vjn4qZCVf2iOupkwEmMe4V2AaEdxI1FJ9dSU8zPkqFhbB3na56eIXgIGwsTWs5WBvlHikTuyYjWNFn6r27qCVfwADGkENoXZG1++vRoRse9X3p5fNqqVNBL1NTBL3k3/hoxB7/A922PT0MTn7rm1I=\"}]}'"
}
```

The problem is obvious:
I am still not creating a proper result selector.

I have json formatted my input in Python:

```
message = {
    'startTime': 12828373,
    'endTime': 12828374
}

# Send message to SQS queue
response = sqs.send_message(
    QueueUrl=queue_url,
    DelaySeconds=10,
    MessageBody=json.dumps(message)
)
```

However, it seems that the step function is grabbing multiple messages. I am also not extracting the data correctly.

Please help with how the result selector should look to extract the startTime & endTime.
Is there anything else I am missing or should be doing different?

My entire step function is below:

```
{
  "Comment": "Run Redshift Queries",
  "StartAt": "ReceiveMessage from SQS",
  "States": {
    "ReceiveMessage from SQS": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Parameters": {
        "QueueUrl": "******"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:sqs:receiveMessage",
      "Next": "Run Analysis Queries",
      "ResultSelector": {
        "startTime.$": "$.Body.startTime",
        "endTime.$": "$.Body.endTime"
      }
    },
    "Run Analysis Queries": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "End": true,
      "Parameters": {
        "ClusterIdentifier": "******",
        "Database": "prod",
        "Sql": "select * from ******"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:redshiftdata:executeStatement"
    }
  },
  "TimeoutSeconds": 3600
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message, the output of your first state is:

```json
{
  "Messages": [
    {
      "Body": "{\"startTime\": 12828373, \"endTime\": 12828374}",
      "Md5OfBody": "1ca004b811be50a7579f3a7e6affaeb1",
      "MessageId": "5b6b72d6-3fb7-451a-9053-26b72de32768",
      "ReceiptHandle": "AQEBjgtt...."
    }
  ]
}
```

So the target is under `$.Messages[0].Body`, which is a JSON string. You could use the built-in intrinsic functions to deal with it:

```json
{
  "Comment": "Run Redshift Queries",
  "StartAt": "ReceiveMessage from SQS",
  "States": {
    "ReceiveMessage from SQS": {
      ...
      "ResultSelector": {
        "body.$": "States.StringToJson($.Messages[0].Body)"
      },
      ...
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

The output of the first state would be:

```json
{
  "body": {
    "startTime": 12828373,
    "endTime": 12828374
  }
}
```

---

If you develop apps with AWS SFN very often, you can subscribe their [What's New Feed](https://aws.amazon.com/new/?whats-new-content-all.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-content-all.sort-order=desc&awsf.whats-new-analytics=*all&awsf.whats-new-app-integration=general-products%23aws-step-functions&awsf.whats-new-arvr=*all&awsf.whats-new-blockchain=*all&awsf.whats-new-business-applications=*all&awsf.whats-new-cloud-financial-management=*all&awsf.whats-new-compute=*all&awsf.whats-new-containers=*all&awsf.whats-new-customer-enablement=*all&awsf.whats-new-customer%20engagement=*all&awsf.whats-new-database=*all&awsf.whats-new-developer-tools=*all&awsf.whats-new-end-user-computing=*all&awsf.whats-new-mobile=*all&awsf.whats-new-gametech=*all&awsf.whats-new-iot=*all&awsf.whats-new-machine-learning=*all&awsf.whats-new-management-governance=*all&awsf.whats-new-media-services=*all&awsf.whats-new-migration-transfer=*all&awsf.whats-new-networking-content-delivery=*all&awsf.whats-new-quantum-tech=*all&awsf.whats-new-robotics=*all&awsf.whats-new-satellite=*all&awsf.whats-new-security-id-compliance=*all&awsf.whats-new-serverless=*all&awsf.whats-new-storage=*all). They will announce new features or improvements here, which might help.

#### References:

- Amazon States Language: https://states-language.net/spec.html
- Intrinsic functions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html